# Impyla hangs on as_pandas()

Tags: python, database, pandas, impala

I have issue with loading data from impala using impyla.
The same code was working for python 2.7, now when I moved to python 3.7 it stopped.

```
connect = connect(host=host_name, port=21050, user=login, password=passwd, use_ssl=True, auth_mechanism='LDAP')
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('USE ' + db_name)
```

The weird thing is that when calling select with count it is working

```
cursor.execute('select count(*) from table')
tab_len = as_pandas(cursor)
```

but with this code it is not

```
cursor.execute('select * from table LIMIT 100')
data = as_pandas(cursor)
```

I checked and it is stacking at

```
cursor.fetchall()
```

There is no error, it is still loading.

Comment: Same issue, seems to be a problem with memory/buffer. select * from xxx limit 18 works in my case, select * from xxx limit 19 hangs. If I reduce to select a,b,c from xxx then the stall occurs at limit 34. Did you find out something in the meantime?